# using mod_rewrite for pretty URLs conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 pages for members profile pages and companies profile pages,
for the members the url should be: `site.com/users/USER_ID`
for the companies the url should be: `site.com/COMPANY_ID`

I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
#Members Profile Page
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1

#Companies Profile Page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
```

But, these 2 rules have conflict which cause the users page also be leaded to `companies_profile.php` since the rule for companies also contain the users profile page in the address.

How I could solve this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just in case we're missing something, please could you post your entire `.htaccess` file in your question?

Comment: Those IDs are numeric? If they aren't, how to prevent the regex for `.../COMPANY_ID` matches everything?

Comment: @faa that's the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`L` rewrite flag](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/L);

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That will stop processing the file once a match is found.

Comment: weird, not working in my case!

Comment: anything comes to your mind why it's not working? thanks

Comment: @behz4d Did you put the flag on the user rules or the company rules or all of them?

Comment: for the users rules as you mentioned, I just also tried with all of them, not working...

Comment: @behz4d Strange, I can see no reason for it to process the company lines then.

Comment: still it goes to companies while the url is /users/etc... :-(